# evorobotpy2 -- PyTypeObject has no tp_print building against Python 3.9

Tags: python, machine-learning, gcc, python-3.7, gcc-warning

So i followed all the instructions to install evorobotpy2(link below) but when i run python3 setupevonet.py build_ext --inplace
i get this error message:

```
running build_ext
skipping 'net.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'net' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fno-semantic-interposition -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fPIC -I/home/vitorh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/lib -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c net.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/net.o
In file included from /home/vitorh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1969,
                 from /home/vitorh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from /home/vitorh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from net.cpp:587:
/home/vitorh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
   17 | #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
      |  ^~~~~~~
net.cpp: In function ‘int __Pyx_modinit_type_init_code()’:
net.cpp:6110:28: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
 6110 |   __pyx_type_3net_PyEvonet.tp_print = 0;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:106,
                 from net.cpp:4:
net.cpp: In function ‘int __Pyx_ParseOptionalKeywords(PyObject*, PyObject***, PyObject*, PyObject**, Py_ssize_t, const char*)’:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  261 |       PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6577:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6577 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:33: warning: ‘Py_UNICODE* PyUnicode_AsUnicode(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  262 |       ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6577:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6577 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
  580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  264 |        PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6577:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6577 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  261 |       PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6577:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6577 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:33: warning: ‘Py_UNICODE* PyUnicode_AsUnicode(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  262 |       ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6577:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6577 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
  580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  264 |        PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6577:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6577 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  261 |       PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6593:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6593 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:33: warning: ‘Py_UNICODE* PyUnicode_AsUnicode(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  262 |       ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6593:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6593 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
  580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  264 |        PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6593:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6593 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  261 |       PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6593:59: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6593 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:33: warning: ‘Py_UNICODE* PyUnicode_AsUnicode(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  262 |       ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6593:59: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6593 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
  580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:61: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  451 | #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH’
  264 |        PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp:6593:59: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyUnicode_GET_SIZE’
 6593 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
  446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
net.cpp: At global scope:
net.cpp:1814:12: warning: ‘int __pyx_pw_3net_8PyEvonet_1__cinit__(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 1814 | static int __pyx_pw_3net_8PyEvonet_1__cinit__(PyObject *__pyx_v_self, PyObject *__pyx_args, PyObject *__pyx_kwds) {
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

I don't know what to do.I am using manjaro and downloaded base-devel,and the other librarys to run the code.
The link to the repo is here https://github.com/snolfi/evorobotpy2

Comment: _Every_ gcc error causes an exit status of 1. It's not a useful thing to put in your title, because it's not specific to the individual problem at all.

Comment: BTW, if you want to ask a question about errors, it'd be easier to see the errors if you turned off the warnings. `-Wall` makes output extremely noisy -- it's useful if you're a maintainer trying to find and fix potential bugs; not so much, if you're a user who just wants to figure out why the thing won't compile.

Comment: ...in this case, your _actual error_ is `‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’`

Comment: and that error implies that the code you're compiling isn't written for the version of Python you're compiling it against. Since you tagged the question `python37` but the error is from compiling against Python 3.9, that's a bit of a smell right there.

Comment: thank you very much, i changed my version of python to 3.7 and it worked. Thanks for the hints too.

Answer (score 1):

Changed to python 3.7 and this solved the problem.